# Given $A \hookrightarrow X$ and $B \hookrightarrow X$ with trivial intersection, when is $A \sqcup B \to X$ also a monomorphism?

Tags: ct.category-theory, pullback

The purpose of this question is to find some general conditions on a category $\mathcal C$ such that the following result is provable.

Consider two monomorphisms $i : A \hookrightarrow X$ and $j : B \hookrightarrow X$, with trivial intersection in the sense that they have a pullback which is an initial object. Suppose also we have a coproduct $A \sqcup B$.

> I would like to know some additional assumptions on $\mathcal C$ that allow me to conclude that the universal morphism $A \sqcup B \to X$ is also a monomorphism.

In particular, these conditions should allow for the case $C = \mathsf{Vect}$, and otherwise "the more general the better".

Comment: Your key-word here is: ``effective unions''. Check, for example, "ON CATEGORIES WITH EFFECTIVE UNIONS" by Michael Barr.

Comment: Funny I didn't notice this question when asking this one [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437194/in-which-categories-is-the-union-of-subobjects-given-by-the-pushout-over-the-int/).